# React Redux: How to render data dynamically on the screen?

Tags: reactjs, redux, frontend

My App has two models: User and Tournament.

With Redux I have an Action/Reducer config that adds a user object to a Tournament object, as an array. So a Tournament can have an array of users (participants)

In component I have a function that calls the redux action for adding a user to a tournament

Here is my Component, including the function for adding users to the tournament, and how its all rendered on the screen.

```
class TournamentShow extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.onSignUp = this.onSignUp.bind(this);
        this.state = {
            participants: []
        };
    };

    static propTypes = {
        tournament: PropTypes.object.isRequired,
        auth: PropTypes.object.isRequired
    };

    onSignUp(tournamentId, user) {
        this.props.addParticipant(tournamentId, user);
    };

    render() {
        const { _id, title, hostedBy, status, participants } = this.props.tournament.showTournament;
        const { isAuthenticated, user } = this.props.auth;
        return (
            <div>
                <h1>{ title }</h1>
                <h3> <TournamentDescription key={_id} title={ title } /> </h3>
                <p>Hosted by: { hostedBy }</p>
                <p>status: { status }</p>
                <p>Registered Fighters:</p>
                <ul>
                    {
                        participants && participants.map(participant => (
                            <li key={participant._id}>{participant.username}</li>
                        ))
                    }
                </ul>
                {
                    status === "Open" && isAuthenticated ?
                    <TournamentSignUp
                        participants={participants}
                        userId={user._id}
                        onClick={() => this.onSignUp(_id, user)} 
                    /> :
                    <Button block disabled>Log in to sign up for this tournament</Button>
                }
                <br/><Link to="/">Back to Tournaments main page</Link>
            </div>
        )
    }
};

const mapStateToProps = state => ({
    tournament: state.tournament,
    auth: state.auth
});

export default connect(mapStateToProps, { showTournament, addParticipant })(TournamentShow);
```

I added State to the class component cuz I believe I need to do something with that

It works well enough.  It adds users to the tournament as a "participant" but I have to refresh the page for it to render on the screen.

Is there a way to do it so that the DOM updates dynamically?

Answer (score 0):

As you may have omitted some parts of the code, I am not sure if you have used `mapStateToProps` in your class.

The idea of this `mapStateToProps` is that any changes on the variables listed there will force a re-render of your component.

Basic implementation is as follows:

```js
const mapStateToProps = state => ({ todos: state.todos })
```

Any changes to your todos variable in your redux will trigger the render in your component.

You may check this documentation for further info:
https://react-redux.js.org/using-react-redux/connect-mapstate

---

You may also want to take note of this [issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48475537/reactjs-reduxmapstatetoprops-not-rendering-the-component-on-state-change). This could also be a reason why your screen is not updated dynamically. As mentioned in the answer in the earlier question:

> MapStateToProps does a shallow compare of the values returned each time. A shallow compare will compare references for objects and arrays.

Comment: I'll update the post to show how i'm using mapStateToProps

Comment: If I already have the tournament object in my mapStateToProps, shouldn't that cause the re-render??

I'll read up on that issue

Comment: You may want to check how addParticipant() works. I think it might be related to the second link I have posted. Try replacing the entire object and not just a field of it.

Comment: Sorry, what do you mean the entire object? Which object?